# S3: Put request to using a pre-signed URL resulting in 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I set up a S3 bucket {bucketName} and an IAM user, {iamUsername}. The user has the following policies to access the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucketName}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucketName}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And the bucket has the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:user/iamUsername"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Other than this, the bucket blocks all public access as recommended by AWS.
I use the access key of the user to pre-sign the URL to upload a file in Flask:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                          aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                          region_name=AWS_REGION)
presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
            'put_object',
            Params={
                'Bucket': S3_BUCKET,
                'Key': random_file_name,
                'ContentType': file_type
            },
            ExpiresIn=3600  # URL expires in 1 hour
        )
```

I use this signed url to upload the file in react:

```
const uploadFile = async (signedUrl) => {
    const uploadFormData = new FormData();
    uploadFormData.append('file', selectedFile);

    try {
        await fetch(signedUrl, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: uploadFormData
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(response);
            throw new Error(response);
          }
          return response.json();
        })
```

This is resulting in a 403, like below:
[403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GoNG.png)

```
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
type: "cors"
url: "https://{bucketName}.s3.amazonaws.com/{fileName}?AWSAccessKeyId={key}&Signature={signature}&content-type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1709497547"
```

Would appreciate help in figuring out what is wrong with the approach, thanks!

PS: I have also set up CORS for my bucket as-

```
    [
        {
            "AllowedHeaders": [
                "*"
            ],
            "AllowedMethods": [
                "GET",
                "PUT",
                "DELETE",
                "HEAD",
                "POST"
            ],
            "AllowedOrigins": [
                "*"
            ],
            "ExposeHeaders": [],
            "MaxAgeSeconds": 3600
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Have you setup the bucket's [CORS configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors.html)?

Comment: @AnonCoward Yes, it looks like this:
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]

Comment: Added the CORS configuration to the question where it might be easier to read :)

Comment: You don't need the bucket policy if the IAM user has S3 permissions.

Comment: **Side-note:** If you are assigning permissions to a particular user, then adding an IAM Policy to the user (your first example) is the recommended method and is sufficient for the task. There is no need to also grant them permission in a Bucket Policy (your second example).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks @jarmod, John Rosenstein. I removed the bucket policy. As expected, the error does not change (screenshot added in the post)

Comment: When calling fetch, include the matching content type e.g. `headers: { "Content-Type": "image/png" }`

Comment: @jarmod Amazing, worked like a charm! Thanks so much for saving my weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you created a pre-signed URL that includes a Content-Type header but you didn't indicate that header later when you used the URL.

If you include HTTP headers at the time you pre-sign the URL then those headers are included in the signing calculation. You need to make sure that the same HTTP headers are sent to S3 in the subsequent HTTP request.

So, when calling fetch, include the matching content type e.g.

```
headers: { "Content-Type": "image/png" }
```

For more pre-signed URL troubleshooting, see [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-presigned-url-signature-mismatch).